# Calculate performance of sql query

Tags: t-sql, parameters, query-performance

I have a query which takes parameter and one which doesn't.
Was trying to compare their performances.
Currently for the query one alone I can see two results.That is totally I get three cost % in my execution plan.
Is there a way to get the two performance cost % instead of three?

```
    ----Query 1
    DECLARE @p2 DATETIME;

    SET @p2 = (
            SELECT max(date_created)
            FROM log_table
            WHERE user_id = 1
            )

    SELECT max(date_created) AS last_login
    FROM log_table
    WHERE date_created <= @p2

  ----Query 2
  SELECT max(date_created) AS last_login
  FROM log_table
  WHERE user_id = 1
```

Comment: The total cost % of 2 queries will be 100% obviously...

Comment: @Milney Yes right.I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you're looking for.
SQL Server produces a plan for each query in the batch.
And you have exactly 3 queries in your batch, because

```
        SELECT max(date_created)
        FROM log_table
        WHERE user_id = 1
```

is also a query.

A compartment of query costs is not always the best way to compare performance.
I suggest you compare the number of reads or average execution time.

Or simply execute them separately, that'll do the trick as well.